# File not found: MANIFEST.MF

Tags: java, maven, jboss

When I deploy my project on JBoss 4.2.3 I have this error
  File not found: C: \ Dev \ workspace \ MyProject \ target \ classes \ META-INF \ MANIFEST.MF.
Have you an idea about this error and how  I can fix

Comment: Your MANIFEST.MF file is missing!

Comment: What project ? via what IDE (if one used) ? configuration ? something ?

Comment: What are you deploying to JBoss? How did you build, whatever you are deploying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for this file in your application. Since the path is hard coded and is valid in your workspace only it cannot be found when application is deployed.

So, to fix this do not look for this file.

There are a lot of questions here.

1. why are you looking for this file at all?
2. If you need manifest you should open it as resource, not as file: `getClass().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF")`

Comment: I base my development from an existing project so how can I  to remove this file?

Comment: I used IDE : eclipse Ganymede
it is a web service created by maven

Comment: In this  target folder the file is already existed so I do not understand this error message